# Weird vertical bar on my desktop

Tags: xorg

I'm not sure how this happened:

[image]

This vertical bar just came out from nowhere, I tried to change workspaces, minimize all application running, no effects.

When it happens I'm only running gvim, chromium, and conky.

So I run xdotoool and click on the bar:

```
%> xdotool selectwindow getwindowpid
window 149 has no pid associated with it.
```

Now what?

Comment: Have you logged out/in (X restart), or restarted the machine?

Comment: @Anthon That works but I tend to solve this problem

Comment: It might just be a memory corruption on your graphics board, cosmic (but not comic) interference.

Comment: sound like device panic, test with a live OS.

Comment: I had similar artifacts when I had GPU capacitor issues.

Comment: I second @DavidKohen hypothesis that it is a GPU hardware fault. Swap out the GPU to test the hypothesis.

Comment: @msw it's a laptop ... builtin Intel Graphics Card

Comment: If I understood your exchange with @Anthon restarting the machine (or X) works for a time but it fails again later. That is *very* diagnostic of a display chip set damaged by overheating. It can easily cost as much to replace the chips as it would to get a new machine. Also, even if the chips were replaced there could be a design defect with the cooling system which can cause the GPU to fail again. Vacuum all the ventilation holes in the laptop and if that doesn't work, consider getting a new one. Sorry.